# Send third party data to Eloqua from a webpage

Tags: eloqua

I would like to send the data about our website visitor, which is obtained from a third party source, to Eloqua from our website.

Suppose, a visitor John is visiting our website ex. www.abc.com. We are getting informations about John from a third party source ex. www.xyz.com. We would like to send these information to Eloqua using the Eloqua page tracking script which is embedded in our website (www.abc.com).

This is identical to sending custom data (dimensions) to google analytics from a website.

I don't know how to achieve my use case in Eloqua. I searched the whole Eloqua documentation and googled the same. But I am not able to find a solid solution yet.

Anybody solved this use case in Eloqua? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can achieve this. You can use the Eloqua API or you can perform a form submission via HTTP to send the data into Eloqua. Which one you use depends on how you're handling the data.

### Using the API

If you're handling things server-side you can use the Eloqua REST API to update/create contact details in Eloqua. It's not secure to do this with JavaScript in the browser as you'll need to provide credentials for API access so this is a server-side only solution. Details about using the API can be found in the [Oracle Eloqua Developer Help Center](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/marketingcs_gs/OMCAB/#Developers/Welcome.htm).

### Using form submissions

Alternatively, You can use simple form submissions. Since this just utilises HTTP requests you can do this from the browser or from a server.

For this solution you need to create a form within Eloqua to handle the data. On this form add in all the fields you require and map them in the form processing steps to suit your requirements. You'd then use this form to send data into Eloqua via AJAX requests from a website or HTTP requests from a server. You can find the form endpoint URL in the 'Integration Details' tab when viewing the form HTML in Eloqua. You will need to ensure you are sending the mandatory form fields which include your Eloqua site ID and the Eloqua form name.

Answer (score 0):

Use query strings to send the data.